# Manipulation-save logging

Tags: hash, logging, validation

I have to keep a journal of all transactions that are performed in my application. Think of an invoice journal.

What options do I have? 
E.g. an option in syslogd, or a table configuration in MySQL would be great.

My goal is to at least be able to prove that the journal has not been manipulated.

Currently I am computing a rolling hashsum of the entries, and send the hashvalue to some trusted  3rd party every 100th entry. That way, I can prove no one has changed a  journal entry and recomputed the whole hash chain.

Comment: [RFC  5848 - Signed Syslog Messages](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5848) - *"...mechanism to add origin authentication,
   message __integrity__, replay resistance, message sequencing, and
   __detection of missing messages__ to the transmitted syslog messages."*

Comment: Oh yes, there exists even a standard for my sought log format. But do I see correctly that there exists no widely used package or library implementing this standard? How do the tens of thousands of accounting and genral financial software suites realize a manipulation-save transaction journal? I mean there must be a gold standard...?

Comment: None of these accounting and financial software will likely use syslog for a transaction journal. And it is likely that there is no standard which will include all use cases of manipulation-save transactions logs since the use cases are too different. But there are general methods to deal with it like having a sequence number included in the message or the previous message (i.e. like a hash chain) etc. The best method to use depends on the specifics and requirements of the actual use case and there is not enough known for your specific case.

Comment: Yes, such a hash chain is exactly what I am doing currently. However, I was searching for some 3rd party tool that is thoroughly tested. In principle, I am in need for a tool that savely stores/archives string messages for me. These messages could for instance be a log of user actions, or processed API instructions. It would have to have the possibility to prove that a log entry has not been maniulated, and that no line has been deleted. However, also a hash chain could be faked by just recomputing all hashes after manipulation.